# How to add an Event Listener on elements that are not yet in the DOM [no-jQuery]?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to attach an event listener (that calls a function) to a button that is not yet present in the DOM. I don't want to use inline-call in the HTML how can I do it?

So far i could achieve what I wanted by creating a `global event listener` that checks if the element clicked has a specific Id. But I found this solution to be dirty and not optimal.

```
const messageForm = document.querySelector("#message-form")
const messageTextarea = document.querySelector("#message-textarea");
const messageList = document.querySelector("#message-list");
const messageEmpty = document.querySelector("#message-empty");
let messageNumber = 0;

const messageFormatted = messageText => {
  return `
  <li class="message-item">
    <img class="message-avatar" src="./icons/boy.png" alt="Username">
      <article class="message-content">
        <p class="author">Ernesto Campese</p>
        <p class="message">${messageText}</p>
        <p class="datetime">A moment ago</p>
      </article>
      <div class="message-actions">
        <img id="message-edit" class="action-button" src="./icons/edit.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
        <img id="message-delete" class="action-button" src="./icons/delete.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
      </div>
  </li>
  `;
}

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.id === "message-delete") {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    messageNumber--;
    messageEmptyCheck();
  }
})

messageForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (messageTextarea.value !== "") {
    messageList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", messageFormatted(messageTextarea.value));
    messageTextarea.value = null;
    messageTextarea.focus();
    messageNumber++;
    messageEmptyCheck();
  }
});
```

As you can see in the code, inside the `<li>` that I'm creating there are two IMG, one is for deleting and the other for editing. I want to add an event listener to the delete IMG, so when the user clicks it, the li gets eliminated.

The problem is that I cannot create any function if the element does not exist yet. I would love to do something like:

```
const messageDeleteButton = document.querySelector("#message-delete");

messageDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
})
```

Hope I was clear enough, thank you guys!

Comment: Attach the listeners to the document level rather than the element level

Comment: @ImmortalDude - See the code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse your HTML string to a `document` in JS and then add the event listener to that element.

So you've got your Template Literal string.

```
const messageFormatted = messageText => {
  return `
  <li class="message-item">
    <img class="message-avatar" src="./icons/boy.png" alt="Username">
      <article class="message-content">
        <p class="author">Ernesto Campese</p>
        <p class="message">${messageText}</p>
        <p class="datetime">A moment ago</p>
      </article>
      <div class="message-actions">
        <img id="message-edit" class="action-button" src="./icons/edit.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
        <img id="message-delete" class="action-button" src="./icons/delete.png" alt="" width="22" height="22">
      </div>
  </li>
  `;
}
```

You can transform your `string` into HTML by writing a function like the one below.
It uses the [`DOMParser API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) which creates a new `document` that will contain all of your HTML you've written in your `string`.

```
const parseStringToHTML = (str) => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  return parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
};
```

And this document works like the one you have in your page, its just a new one that only exists in your JS memory for the time being. Give your `string` as argument to `parseStringToHTML` to create HTML.

```
const message = messageFormatted('This is the message'); // Example message
const messageHTML = parseStringToHTML(message); // Returns a document object with all the features a document object has.
```

So now that your `string` is a `document` you can use methods on it like `getElementById`, `querySelector`, etc. But **first** you must select the element that you need.

```
const messageDeleteButton = messageHTML.querySelector("#message-delete");
```

See that I've used `messageHTML` instead of `document`. In this scenario `messageHTML` *is* a `document` and therefor we can query inside of it. And now you've found your element inside this `document` you can add an event listener to it.

```
messageDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
});
```

Okay, so now the event listener has been added. All you have to do now is append the HTML you need from the `messageHTML` into the `document` of your page. The HTML can be found in the `messageHTML.body` property.

Now instead of `insertAdjacentHTML` use [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) to insert the element in the position of your choosing. The element you want to append is the `<li class="message-item">` which would be the `firstElementChild` in the `body` of the `messageHTML.body` property.

So in your `submit` event listener of your form change the following line from:

```
messageList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", messageFormatted(messageTextarea.value));
```

To all that I've explained above.

```
// Create string
const message = messageFormatted(messageTextarea.value);

// String to document
const messageHTML = parseStringToHTML(message);

// Select delete element.
const messageDeleteButton = messageHTML.querySelector("#message-delete");

// Add event listener to delete element.
messageDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {   
    e.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
});

// Append the <li> element to the messageList.
messageList.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", messageHTML.body.firstElementChild);
```

Don't forget to include the `parseStringToHTML` function in your code. I understand that this is a lot to work out so if you have any question please do ask.

I hope that this will help you out.

**Note** I see that event delegation (global event listener) is not something you want to do, although as other have stated, it is more performant and easier to implement than other methods, even my own answer. It would also solve listening for elements that you've added or even removed from your list. You could set it even on the `<ul id="message-list">` element like **T.J. Crowder suggested**.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The identifying characteristic doesn't have to be an `id`, it can be anything about the element — a class is a common approach.

There are three DOM methods that will help with making the implementation flexible:

- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) - starting with the element you call it on, it finds the nearest ancestor matching a given CSS selector
- [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) - checks to see if a node contains another node
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) - checks to see if the element you call it on matches a given CSS selector

For instance, your current handler requires that the button be the element that was clicked (`event.target`). That's fine for your `img` use case, but what if it were a `button` with an `img` inside it? Then `event.target` might be the `button` of the `img`, depending on where the user clicked. `closest` and `contains` help with that:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const button = e.target.closest("#message-delete");
  if (button) {
    button.closest("li").remove();
    messageNumber--;
    messageEmptyCheck();
  }
})
```

You'll also want to hook the events on the nearest container that will work. Sometimes, you're stuck with it being `document` or `document.body`. But oftentimes, you can do better than that. For instance, when listening for button clicks on buttons that are in the cells of a table, you can listen at the `table` or `tbody`/`thead` level rather than document. That's where `contains` comes into the equation, it makes sure `closest` didn't go too far up the document tree:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-table").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const button = e.target.closest("#message-delete");
  if (button && e.currentTarget.contains(button)) {
  //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    button.closest("li").remove();
    messageNumber--;
    messageEmptyCheck();
  }
})
```

It's not likely in your case that the search for `#message-delete` will have gone out of the containing element, so you may not need that bit, but sometimes it can happen and so you want that `contains` check.

Comment: Lemme say this, if you hook up a document like that with multiple event listeners, you will get in problems rather sooner as later. Image you have a message delete button, message upvote button, message whatever and so on. This is not to criticize you but for every click in the document or the container the engine has to work. If you summon the element, hook the listener on to the element and not use a big 250mm cannon for shooting a little fence.

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs That's true! But that's a problem of scoping and not of this approach.

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs - Hence *"You'll also want to hook the events on the nearest container that will work."* But you'd need several hundred if not more, even on mobile, for `click` to be a problem. (`mousemove` on the other hand...)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add event listener to that element itself then I think you may want to try MutationObserver -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You can observe the events with passing config for childList, subtree and on the event you can check whether the element you are looking for has been added or it is there. If you find that you can add the event listener.

You may want to look at following articles - 
https://eager.io/blog/three-real-world-use-cases-for-mutation-observer/
https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401

I hope it would be helpful.