# Changing class without variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have attached 2 of my divs below. When the icon inside heart is clicked, if the class name is far then it should change from far to fas. But if the class name has been changed to fas, it should change back to far. I'm not sure how to do this becuase I have many divs.

```
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i onclick="like(example)"  class="fas fa-heart"></i>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header#2</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i onclick="like1()"  class="fas fa-heart"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I currently have.

```
function like(example){
     if(example.classList=="far fa-heart"){
         example.classList.toggle="fas fa-heart";
     } else{
         example.classList.toggle="far fa-heart";
    }
}
```

I want this to be in just 1 function without making a variable for all the  tags in javascript. I'm still learning... Thanks for your help!

Comment: There has to be a good dupetarget for this. Basically: Hook `click` on the container of these, and if the click bubbled through the `fa-heart` element, toggle the `far` and `fas` classes on it. Search for "event delegation" for more on the concept.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748060/how-to-add-an-event-listener-on-elements-that-are-not-yet-in-the-dom-no-jquery/57748124#57748124

Comment: The updated code does not match the example provided. 1) you only want to toggle a single class. 2) you’re not passing `this` as the answer shows. 3) still probably better to use the click event handler instead of the `onClick` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the answer to add the HTML and import fontawesome, since my first answer was done on my phone.

```js
function toggleHearts() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".heart")
    .forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.classList.toggle("far");
      e.target.classList.toggle("fas");
    }));
}

toggleHearts()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>A header</h2>
  <div class="heart">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>A header#2</h2>
  <div class="heart">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a good dupetarget for this. Basically, you can hook `click` on a parent element containing all of these (`body` if nothing else) and only take action if the click passed through the `fa-heart` element when bubbling:

```
theContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Did the click pass through an `.fa-heart` element?
    const heart = event.target.closest(".fa-heart");
    if (heart && this.contains(heart)) {
        // Yes, and that element is inside this container; toggle it
        heart.classList.toggle("far");
        heart.classList.toggle("fas");
    }
});
```

See [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), and [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) for details.

Live Example:

```js
const theContainer = document.body;
theContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Did the click pass through an `.fa-heart` element?
    const heart = event.target.closest(".fa-heart");
    if (heart && this.contains(heart)) {
        // Yes, and that element is inside this container; toggle it
        heart.classList.toggle("far");
        heart.classList.toggle("fas");
    }
});
```

```css
.fa-heart {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.fas {
    background-color: red;
}
.fas::after {
    content: 'fas';
}
.far {
    background-color: green;
}
.far::after {
    content: 'far';
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header#2</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that accepts an HTML element as a parameter and toggles the classes.

```js
function like1(element) {  
  element.classList.toggle("fas");
  element.classList.toggle("far");
}
```

```css
.fas {
  color: green;
}
.far {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i onclick="like1(this)"  class="fas fa-heart">Like</i>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
     <h2>A header#2</h2>
     <div class="heart">
          <i onclick="like1(this)"  class="fas fa-heart">Like</i>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do I put in the parameter?

Comment: @Leena - What do you mean? Vid has shown the code using the parameter (`element`).

Comment: I don't recommend suggesting continuing using `onXYZ`-style attribute handlers. They can only call global functions, for one thing.

Comment: The parameter should be the clicked element, so using `onclick="like1(this)"` passes the clicked element onto your function.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to javascript. (element) means that the specific element I clicked regarless of there being the same element in 2 different cards?

Comment: @Leena yes, each HTML element is an object in Javascript. So even if 2 HTML elements are exactly the same, they're still 2 different Javascript objects.

Comment: okay, I got the toggle to work but by selecting the specific Id but how do I select the element that has been clicked?

Comment: @Leena you don't need to. If you pass `this` into your function in the `onclick="like1(this)"` you're already passing the clicked element object into your function as a parameter.

Comment: But, the code isn't working.... The console error is this ->  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'toggle')

Comment: Add your updated code below your original question and I'll take a look.

Comment: function like(example){
    if(example.classList=="far fa-heart"){
        example.classList.toggle="fas fa-heart";
    } else{
        example.classList.toggle="far fa-heart";
    }
    }

This code still doesn't work. Can someone help me?